# Get child processes of a main process without System.Management

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

Trying to get process information of dotnet core services that are actively running.

Services on Linux for `dotnet` are done like;

`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'PATH=/sbin/dotnet:$PATH exec dotnet /path/to/dotnetcore.dll'`

We're getting all processes by going:

`foreach (var p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()) {}`

For each process the `ProcessName` value is `dotnet`, and can get the memory size, etc.  But when there are multiple services that are running via `dotnet` we don't know which service it's associated to, as the `ProcessName` is just `dotnet`.

Current answers out on the Internet use `System.Management` which is not supported on Linux.

I know I can use a workaround with bash execute `systemctl status <servicename>` or `systemctl show <servicename>` and then `grep` the output.  But I'm looking for a modern solution, in purely .Net code.

Comment: `Process.Modules` may help you determine what DLL's running under the hood.

Comment: I tried that and it lists a lot of modules, but nothing that points to the DLL that was loaded.  It looks like mostly modules that `dotnet` loaded for its own operation, but not listing the DLL that it was created to run that I can see.